# Puede una excepción mostrar un mensaje en JOption?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public class noEs_HardyException extends Exception  {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public noEs_HardyException() {

        super("El numero NO es Hardy Ramanujan! ");
    }


}
```

Pero quiero que cada vez que se llame muestre su mensaje en un JOption y no en consola, Se podria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directamente desde la excepción no. Pero como toda excepción puedes ponerla en un `try/catch` y en el `catch` mostrar el JOption:

```
       try {

        //codigo que lanza la excepción del tipo noEs_HardyException

        } catch (noEs_HardyException ex) {

            //mostrar JOption con el mensaje de la excepcion
        }
```